# python-redfish: $HOME environment variable not set, please check your system

Tags: python, environment-variables

I tried to import the python lib called "redfish" but was in vain; I import another lib(os) first and seems ok:

```
>>> import os
>>> import redfish
    $HOME environment variable not set, please check your systemPS    
C:\Users\user>
```

I also checked the environment variable; I use Enthought Canopy as my python IDE:

[image]

And python is also added to system variable: 
[image]

[image]

And then I used python console, tried to get HOME, but it shows nothing

[image]

I've searched for a while but no related issues when users import python redfish lib, maybe redfish is a new BMC standard so not widely-used currently for pyhton-users. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Where you took the second screenshot do you see `HOMEPATH` under the first column?

Comment: I don't see `$HOME` listed in the screenshots. Is it anywhere outside the visible regions?

Comment: @Evert,  hi, please see the updated pic, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the path of redfish packages :

```
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)
>>>..................................................
   ..................................................
   C:\users\user\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user
   *C:\users\user\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages*
```

and then add it to the system variable $HOME, and open python shell again to import the lib and it works.

```
>>> import os
>>> HOME = os.getenv('HOME')
>>> HOME
'C:/users/user/appdata/local/enthought/canopy/user/lib/site-packages/'
>>> import redfish
>>> redfish.connect
 <function connect at 0x0000000003E6B898>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in the terminal

1. `pip uninstall python-redfish`
2. `pip uninstall python`
3. `pip install python`